# How to use salt-stack send files from VM datastore to a minion in that datastore

Tags: vmware, datastore, salt-stack, vsphere, vcenter

I use salt-stack & vSphere Web to manage a vCenter server. There many virtual machines run in this, so I use one vm as salt-master.

There are some files in the vCenter's datastore. And I want to send these files to a minion.

[Image of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRsTT.png)

I have tried different ways many times. For example, I tried changing the datastore in `cloud.profiles.d/.conf`. Nothing has worked so far.

It's almost like I can't use salt to control datastore any more.

Comment: salt-cloud are only used to provisioned cloud instances, e.g. create new vm instance.  If you want to copy some file to salt-minion after provisioned, you need modules that are able to access the vcenter datastore.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the mount.mounted. Nothing has worked so far.

So, I use the " virtual hard " on vSphere Web Client instead of it. It works.